# Pulling out a product only once from a django view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm coming across a small problem with pulling out a list of products from my Django view. I have a product page which pulls through all of the products in my model where the 'active' tick box is ticked. You can also assign sub products to the these products.

If the product has a sub product assigned to it, rather then loading a page with more content it will load a page with a list of the sub products. However at the moment in the template it loops through and pulls out all of the products. However at the moment if a product has 1 or more sub products assigned to it, it will pull through each product more than once, depending on how many sub products it has assigned to it.

The reason for this is because I've created a chain which combines two variables together in the function in the view. But I need to do this in order for the sub products to work.

So basically what I need to do is limit each product to only appear once on the template, no matter how many sub products it has assigned to it.

If you need any more info please ask! :)

**UPDATED VIEW WITH ANSWER **

VIEW:

```
def producthome(request):
    #prod_info= Product.objects.filter(active=True, sub_product__isnull = True)
    #sub_product = Product.objects.filter(sub_product__isnull = False, active=True)


    partner_post= Partner.objects.all()

    product_all = Product.objects.filter(active=true)

    #product_all = list(chain(prod_info, sub_product))

    """
    Didn't need to chain the querysets together

    product_all = sorted(
        chain(prod_info, sub_product),
        key = attrgetter('order'), reverse=True)
    """

    return render_to_response('product_multi.html',{
        'product_all': product_all,
        'sub_product': sub_product,
        'prod_info': prod_info,
        'partner_post': partner_post
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{% for product in product_all %}


                    <li>



                        <div>
                        <h2 class="posttitle colortext">{{ product.name }}</h2>
                        <p>{{ product.description|safe|truncatewords:13 }}...</p>
                       <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="button">More</a>
                        </div>

                    </li>



    {% endfor %}
```

***ANSWER***

Turns out I didn't need to chain the querysets I could just pull out the products together. As there was another function doing the other work. Apologies for the confusion but thanks. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you are chaining querysets, nor the problem you are trying to solve, could you elaborate more on the subject and extend your snippet with relevant code. Btw you should probably implement a [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) to deal with product hierarchy.

Comment: Perhaps the `distinct` method is what you're looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Just for the record: you'd get the very same products sequence just using `products_all = Products.objects.filter(active=True).order_by("-order")`. If you don't understand why then it would be time to learn about programming and the relationnal model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER

Turns out i didn't need to chain the querysets I could just pull out the products together. As there was another function doing the other work. Apologies for the confusion but thanks. I've updated the answer.